# Cloning HTML element with Alpine.js component

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom, alpine.js

I have Html element with Alpine.js component. I would like to be able to clone it (using jQuery). Unfortunatelly it does not work - when using `x-for` I'm getting:

> ReferenceError: option is not defined

and in fact some element content is duplicated ("one two three" is displayed twice for each paragraph)

Obviously code here is simplified (in fact I want to clone custom dropdowns with more component methods) but I believe simpolified code clearly shows the problem.

Html code:

```
<div>

<p x-data="{...CustomComponent}" x-init="initialize()">
  <template x-for="option in options">
     <span x-text="option"></span>
  </template>
</p>

</div>

<button>Clone element</button>
```

JavaScript code:

```
const CustomComponent = (function() {

  return {
  
    options: [],
    initialize()
    {    
      this.options = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
    }
  }
}());


$('button').on('click', function() {
    $('div').append($('p').first().clone());

});
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ut8g4p1d/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the solution is to have copy of element that won't be parsed until it's cloned:

Html:

```
<div>


<p x-data="{...CustomComponent}" x-init="initialize()">
  <template x-for="option in options">
     <span x-text="option"></span>
  </template>
</p>

</div>

<button>Clone element</button>

<template class="tpl">
  <p x-data="{...CustomComponent}" x-init="initialize()">
    <template x-for="option in options">
       <span x-text="option"></span>
    </template>
  </p>
</template>
```

JavaScript:

```
const CustomComponent = (function() {

  return {
  
    options: [],
    initialize()
    {
      this.options = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
    }
  }
}());


$('button').on('click', function() {

    $('div').append($('template.tpl').html());

});
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r23e6v9s/)